# White Text in Select Box Options - HTML Dialog in Google App Script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4, google-workspace

I am building some customer HTML dialog for Google Sheets.  The page in question will be a form for creating a work order.  I am using Bootstrap 4 for the styling and I have some added JS inside the document for showing and hiding some elements.  I am not finished with the code yet, I ran the script in Google Sheets and discovered two problems.

I have several select boxes within the form, they are populated with a blank (as the initial selected option), an option for "New" and when I am finished a script will dynamically populate the rest of the options(the option "Existing" is temporary). When I load the page from Google Sheets the select boxes are white text with white back ground.  When something is selected it will show up in the input box as black text but the user can't see the options.

The other problem is the date input.  I am using the browser input calendar popup.  Once the html is loaded the calendar is cut off and you can only see a few days to choose from.  Everyone using this will be on Desktop Chrome, so no worries with mobile or cross browser compatibility.

For the problem with the select box I have tried to add a color style tag to the options in the select box but that didn't help, and for the calendar I have no idea what the solution could be.

The code that loads the page

```
function createWO() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("createWO").evaluate().setTitle("Create Work Order").setWidth(1500).setHeight(1000);
   SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Create New WorkOrder');
}
```

The Snippets from the HTML

Metatags in head

```html
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Style Sheet Reference in head

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Select box causing problem

```html
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="custID">Customer Name</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="custID" onchange="customer(this.value);">
                                    <option selected></option>
                                    <option value="1">New</option>
                                    <option>Existing Customer</option>
                                <!--Script Will Populate Select Box-->
                                </select> 
                            </div>
```

Java Script for onChange event in select box

```java
        <!-- Document JavaScript -->
    <script>
    function customer(value) {
        if (value=='1')
            document.getElementById('hiddencustomer').style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById('hiddencustomer').style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
```

Bootstrap required script references

```html
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve] and Please limit yourself to one question at a time.

Comment: Your white lettering is probably coming from bootstrap-4.

Comment: I edited the code to only include applicable code and got rid of the second questions.

Comment: Is this a known problem in bootstrap 4 or was that just a suggestion?

Comment: The white lettering is not a Google Problem.

Comment: I'd suggest discarding all the css and just get the form working first.